# ko.utils.extend Doesn't Override Property From Model

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Why `ko.utils.extend` doesn't override `this.selectItem` ? Here it always shows alert of 1.

```
         var ViewModel = function () {
           this.selectItem = function () { alert(1) };
          };
        }

        ko.utils.extend(ViewModel.prototype, {
            selectItem: function () {
                alert("from extend");
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `extend` doesn't override it is that it's not a prototype property. It's a property added to the *instance* by the constructor function, which shadows (hides) the prototype property.

Here's the order of what occurs *(note - I've fixed the syntax errors in the code in the question, and added an instantiation of the view model)*:

```
// 1 - the `ViewModel` function is created, along with `ViewModel.prototype`
var ViewModel = function () {
    // 4 - the instance gets its own `selectItem` property
    this.selectItem = function () { alert(1) };
};

// 2 - `selectItem` is added to `ViewModel.prototype`
ko.utils.extend(ViewModel.prototype, {
    selectItem: function () {
        alert("from extend");
    }
});

// 3 - an instance is created; its underlying prototype is set from `ViewModel.prototype`
var vm = new ViewModel();
```

Comment: But if I use this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);. It works fine, it takes the function from extend. Why ?

Comment: @theChampion: Because then you're using the prototype's version of the function and binding `this` to it, and then giving the instance its own property (shadowing the prototype's property) by assigning back the bound version.

Comment: So when I use bind(this) then it finds the context of the model and shadow the property which is inside the model and uses the new one. Am I right ?

Comment: Your `this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);` does this: 1. Read the `selectItem` property from the instance; it doesn't have one, so the engine looks at the prototype. It has one, so we use that value. 2. Call `bind` on that to create a bound function. 3. Create a `selectItem` property on the instance which refers to the bound function.

Comment: I initialize this.selectItem with the bind(this) in the instance. Why the engine doesn't find the property from the instance and looks inside the prototype? Does the function bind returns function in the instance? The 1,2,3 points the engine or bind makes these steps ?

Comment: @theChampion: *"Why the engine doesn't find the property from the instance and looks inside the prototype?"* Because at that point, the instance doesn't have a `selectItem` property; its prototype does, but it doesn't. After the assignment is complete, *then* the instance has its own `selectItem` property. *"Does the function bind returns function in the instance?"* I'm not sure I understand that question. The function `bind` returns is a function that, when called, will call the original with `this` set to the value you passed `bind`.

Comment: @theChampion: *"The 1,2,3 points the engine or bind makes these steps ?"* The engine. It would be the same if you had an `a` property on the prototype with the value `0` and then did `this.a = this.a + 1;` in the constructor. The `a` in `this.a + 1` is read from the prototype, we add one to it, and then the `this.a = (the result)` creates an `a` property on the instance.

Comment: Ok I will explain all what I understand point by point. 

1 - Before the initialization of the instance of type ViewMdel ko.utils.extend(...) is initializing new properties in the ViewModel prototype.

2 - Knockout creates instance of ViewModel and bind this.selectItem with this.selectItem.bind(this) (this.selectItem from the right side is the property from the prototype which is already initialized when ko.utils.extend(...) was running).

Comment: @theChampion: I don't think it's Knockout that creates the viewmodel. Presumably you have the `new ViewModel()` call in *your* code, and then you pass the resulting instance into KO.

Comment: Yes in this case. But I saw this in one Knockout example. Thank you for the explanation. I think I understand now.